# Is there a freeware alternative to Tableau 8?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, tableau

Is there a freeware alternative to Tableau 8? One that allows me to use my own data (shapefiles)? 
Tableau is a comercial software that permits you to create a dashboard were you can show at same time maps e diferent kind of graphs. Besides it is very limited for a GIS, it could be very useful to make simpler visual analysis and communicate results in a interactive environment. As my specialty is environmental analysis, like vulnerability analysis, my main interest is to find a tool to communicate the results and that allows anyone to do simple analysis, like correlation graphics (see the link for example http://esl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/). There is some tools in the market but or they are expensive, or they do not permit that you use your own data.

Tableau 8 http://www.tableausoftware.com/new-features/8.0

Comment: QGIS http://qgis.org/en/site/about/index.html ?

Comment: @Sidney Can you give a description of what Tableau does and which aspects or functionality you are most interested in replicating in an open-source GIS. I must admit that the link didn't reveal much to me about what this software actually does. Thanks.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev from my experience with it, Tableau has a great deal of powerful data analysis capabilities, somewhat like Pivot Tables but very, very flexible and with good graphical representation of data. Its mapping aspects are (in some ways) limited compared to a GIS package like QGIS or ArcGIS, and it uses the map as a baseplate on which to display data (it can do choropleth, pie charts, proportional symbols, etc.). I'd be interested to hear more about what Sidney wants to replicate.

Comment: @Erica Thanks for the information. I had never heard of the software before now so this it is interesting to learn about it.

Comment: I actually used it in a dynamic cartography class, and it was largely introduced because the professor had heard about it and wanted a chance to play with it :D

Comment: @Erica. My main interest is to create some kind of dashboards to communicate my results in a easy, friendly and interactive way, so non gis expert users can better incorporate the information. The millenium development goals dashboard (the link is above) is a good example.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a few options.

1) [ArcGIS online](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline) if your data are limited and you just want to get it online (they have free limited use for individuals).

2) [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/) if you need something more robust and are more server focused.

3) [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) if want you want is more mobile.

But as whitebox says, it depends exactly what features of Tableau you want (want an awful link for a commercial product, a complete lack of information).